How to reliably find and scroll a scrollable widget in Flutter with function?
Here's the widget I am using:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const settings = Center(
      child: Text(
        'Home 1',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white
        ),
      ),
    );
    const settings2 = Center(
      child: Text(
        'Home 2',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white
        ),
      ),
    );
    const children = <Widget>[
      ListTile(
        title: settings
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings2
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings2
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings2
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings2
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings2
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings2
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings2
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings2
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings2
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings2
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings2
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: settings2
      ),
    ];

    return Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        key: GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'home'),
        controller: ScrollController(),
        child: const Column(children: children),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Here's the way I fetch the scrollable state:
final dynamic renderObject = key.currentContext!.findRenderObject();
final dynamic scrollableContext = key.currentContext;
final ScrollableState scrollableState = Scrollable.of(scrollableContext);

Here's the error message I received:
No Scrollable widget ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to Scrollable.of(). This can happen because you are using a widget that looks for a Scrollable ancestor, but no such ancestor exists.

The context can be confirmed to be attached to the SingleChildView, but it still says there's no scrollable ancestor. I wonder what happened.

ScrollablePositionedList I preferred if you'd like to locate an item and scroll to it in a ListView (https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list).
You can use ItemScrollController to scrollTo or jumpTo the valid place wherever you want via index (item position) at ease.
itemScrollController.scrollTo({
  required int index,
  required Duration duration,
  double alignment = 0,
});

